# Why Swarm so slow? No peers found?

Tags: swarm

I made

```
# swarm up 1.mp4
58740257f3519e1e20a85994eefc3a4d8d40ac5f8649d5acf93d174676279ad5
```

and push 497Mb video to swarm. Swarm works and connected to my account.

When I try in Chrome

> localhost:8500/bzz:/58740257f3519e1e20a85994eefc3a4d8d40ac5f8649d5acf93d174676279ad5

everything is ok. Video starts, because this is local node, where video.

But when I try in Chrome external node (public or my remote server),

> https://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/58740257f3519e1e20a85994eefc3a4d8d40ac5f8649d5acf93d174676279ad5
>
> http://myserver.com/bzz:/58740257f3519e1e20a85994eefc3a4d8d40ac5f8649d5acf93d174676279ad5

this video not loading, or loading very very slow by chunks.

I tested 100Mb video - almost the same. Only when I push index.html with only "Hello World" - I saw this using https://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:

I tried to add peers using this manual https://swarm-gateways.net/bzz:/swarm-gateways.eth/   - No success.

Do Swarm have peers?  Swarm works or not now? Can I use it for large files or it worth only for 1kb index.html?